# How to call React class component from normal JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wanted to call the React class component from the JavaScript function which is defined in the another file. Here  React Class component having  the JSX syntax. Is it possible ?

This is my React Class component defined in the file Example.js

```
class Example extends React.Component {
     render() {
        return <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>;
     }
}
```

This is my normal JavaScript function defined in the file Normal.js . From this function I wanted to call my React class component. How to call ?

```
function Calling() {
   //From Here I wanted to call React Class component (Example) 

}
```

Comment: Can you please provide some more details of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: <Example> write this inside calling function, it will call the example component

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Its not working and giving an error. 
"You are using the in-browser Babel transformer. Be sure to precompile your scripts for production"